# Installing a python wrapper for windows for Stanford NLP?

Tags: python, wrapper, stanford-nlp

I want to use a python wrapper in Windows for Stanford NLP. I have tried Jpype and one by Dasmith. But ran into bugs. I think the code is buggy. Can anyone confirm if they have used above two for windows.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find [a list of Python wrappers for CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/other-languages.html#python) in the CoreNLP documentation. As a descendant of the dasmith version, you might try the WordSeer fork, or Brendan O'Connor's Python wrapper. More recently, we have released a Java web service, and Smitha Millia's wrapper talks directly to it. That may be more reliable (though the Python client is currently fairly basic).